# Does Volatile variable makes sense here(multi-core processor)?

Tags: java, volatile

I declared a instance variable as voltile. Say two threads are created by two processors under multi core where thread updates the variable. To ensure
instantaneous visibilty, I believe declaring variable as volatile is right choice here so that update done by thread happens in main memory and is visible to another thread .
Right?

Intention here to understand the concept in terms of multicore processor.

Comment: What type is the variable?

Comment: @weston An "instance variable" is the same thing as "field".

Comment: I think you should post some code it is far too vague what is going on. Are you updating the reference, or the content of the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are considering using `volatile` vs. not using any special provisions for concurrency (such as `synchronized` or `AtomicReference`).

It is irrelevant whether you are running single-code or multicore: sharing data between threads is *never* safe without `volatile`. There are many more things the runtime is allowed to do without it; basically it can pretend the accessing thread is the only thread running on the JVM. The thread can read the value once and store it on the call stack forever; a loop reading the value, but never writing it, may be transformed such that the value is read only once at the outset and never reconsidered, and so on.

So the message is simple: use `volatile`—but that's not necessarily *all* you need to take care of in concurrent code.

Comment: "sharing data between threads is never safe without volatile" No! How about a sync block?

Comment: @weston It should be clear from the context that we are discussing `volatile` vs. nothing at all. Of course other measures which induce *happens-before* relationships are OK---such as `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Whether the value itself is immutable or not is irrelevant here: we're discussing the visibility of writes to the instance variable. If the value is mutable and will change after publication, then just the `volatile` isn't enough (my last paragraph is about that).

Comment: what would happen if multiple write happening at different threads on same volatile variable concurrently?

Comment: The writes would have a definite order of occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if it's done by different processors or not. When you don't have mult-processors, you can still run into concurrency problems because context switches may happen any time.

If a field is not volatile, it may still be in one thread's cache while its context is switched out and the other thread's context switches in. In that case, the thread that just took over the (single) processor will not see that the field has changed.

Since these things can happen even with one processor, they are bound to happen with more than one processor, so indeed, you need to protect your shared data.

Whether `volatile` is the right choice or not depends on what type it is and what kind of change you are trying to protect from. But again, that has nothing to do with the number of processors.

If the field is a reference type, then `volatile` only ensures the vilibility of new assignments to the field. It doesn't protect against changes in the object it points to - for that you need to synchronize.

Comment: Just one clarification: a write to a reference-typed `volatile` does guarantee that all changes to the object preceding the write will be visiible to a thread after it reads the reference. In other words, `volatile` is all it takes to *safely publish* an object to other threads, provided that the object doesn't change after publication.

Comment: what would happen if multiple write happening at different threads on same volatile variable concurrently?